# When inside an if statement condition why cant I execute a function and test the result

Tags: bash

I want to run a function from inside my if statement condition, but I'm unsure on how it should be written in one line.

My function looks like this:

```
MyFunction(){
fuctionArg1=$1
functionArg2=$2
echo "Inside the function, arg1 is $functionArg1"
echo "Inside the function, arg2 is $functionArg2"

return 1
}
```

I currently have this if statement:

```
arg1=10
arg2=20

MyFunction $arg1 $arg2
if [ $? == 1 ] ; then
echo "Hello"
else
echo "Nothing"
fi
```

But why doesn't something like this below work? It currently only seems to return as 1 even when the MyFunction return value is set to 0:

```
arg1=10
arg2=20


if [ "$(MyFunction "$arg1" "$arg2")" == 1 ] ; then
echo "Hello"
else
echo "Nothing"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using command substitution I don't think this is possible.

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the
>   command itself.

So what will be tested in the if statement would be the output from the function (the echo statements).

Without the echo statements, there is no output, so the if statement is always evaluated as false.

What you can do is just pass the function call as an argument to `if`. Note though that the if expression is evaluated as true if `return 0`, false if `return 1`. Which I believe is the Linux convention - to return 0 indicates success, non-zero indicates an error state.

```
if MyFunction "$arg1" "$arg2; then
   echo "Hello"
else
   echo "Nothing"
fi
```

In `MyFunction` return 0. Or return 1 and negate the expression thus:

```
if ! MyFunction "$arg1" "$arg2; then
```

Comment: @Bobybobp You should quote command sub like `if [ "$(MyFunction "$arg1" "$arg2")" == 1 ] ; then`

Comment: @oguzismail What you have suggested is exactly the same as what I tried in my question, it always returns the same value, even when the MyFunction return value is changed.

Comment: @Bobybobp Modified post - I don't think it's possible to return from a function and use the return value inside an if test.